# What subjects did Dumbledore teach in Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

What subject did Professor Albus Dumbledore teach when he was recruited as a teacher in Hogwarts. Also, till his death, what other subjects did he teach.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

He was a [Transfiguration](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Transfiguration_%28class%29) teacher. From *Chamber of Secrets*, Tom Riddle tells Harry:

> 'Only **the Transfiguration teacher, Dumbledore**, seemed to think Hagrid was innocent. He persuaded Dippet to keep Hagrid and train him as gamekeeper. Yes, I think Dumbledore might have guessed. Dumbledore never seemed to like me as much as the other teachers did...' *(CHAPTER SEVENTEEN, The Heir of Slytherin)*

Comment: Is that the first & only course he officially taught at Hogwarts?

Comment: @KharoBangdo - It's the only one I remember mentioned in any of the books or interviews. Wikia also doesn't list any additional ones.

Answer (score 3):

Now that Fantastic Beast 2 trailer has come out, we know that Dumbledore not only taught Transfiguration, but Defense against the Dark Arts as well.

Comment: Which of course makes him rather unusual, even as a teacher. Nowhere else do we see a teacher who teaches more than one class (except for the occasional substituting, like Snape teaching DaDA when Lupin is ill).

Comment: The trailer shows Dumbledore teaching his students about bogarts, which is not necessarily defense against the dark arts. There is definitely an argument to be said that bogarts are a good study of transfiguration (that's what they do, they transfigure themselves into something you fear most!). Just because we know Lupin taught students about bogarts in defense against the dark arts, and that it appears to be the same room that dumbledore is using for his lessons on bogarts, does not mean that dumbledore taught defence against the dark arts!

Comment: See this article (before the movie was released) for more details (but not definitive answers):
https://www.therowlinglibrary.com/2018/07/17/is-dumbledore-teaching-defense-against-the-dark-arts/

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Quirrell did teach Muggle Studies before DADA, too.

Comment: @Lewis Before, yes (just like Snape switches from Potions to DaDA in _HBP_); but never simultaneously.

Comment: @ZenLogic I’m now having visions of Humphrey Bogart jumping out of a wardrobe with a vulture on his head. :-p

Answer (score 1):

Dumbledore taught Transfiguration, like  Minerva Mcgonagall during the events of book 1 to 7. I think it's said in *Chambers of Secret*, when young Tom Marvolo Riddle shows his memories to Harry. I'll try to find the exact quote later.

I don't think he's taught anything else.